# how do i sort the data from back end in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
 return (
            <tr key={item.id}>
                <td><Link to={"/risk/view/" + item.id} className="clickable-link">{item.name}</Link></td>
                <td>{item.description ? constructDescription(item.description) : ""}</td>
                <td>{item.riskOwner.firstName + " " + item.riskOwner.lastName}</td>
                <td style={{ color: statusColor }}>{item.formStatus.title}</td>
                <td>{item.entityInherentRisk ? item.entityInherentRisk.displayName : ""}</td>
                <td>{item.entityResidualRisk ? item.entityResidualRisk.displayName : ""}</td>
                <td>
                    {canEdit ?
                        <div><Link to={"/risk/edit/" + item.id} className="clickable-link"><span className="icon icon-file"></span> </Link>
                            <Link to={"/risk/view/" + item.id} className="clickable-link" > | <a href="#" className="clickable-link"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> </a></Link>
                            {canDelete ? <a href="#" className="clickable-link"> | <i className="icon icon-delete" onClick={() => { this.initiateDelete(item) }}></i> </a> : null}
                        </div> :
                        <Link to={"/risk/view/" + item.id} className="clickable-link"><a href="#"><i className="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a></Link>}
                </td>
            </tr>
            )
```

I have a list of data displayed in my Web page. I would like to add a sort button to that list and would like to sort that list to ascending and descending. how can i do that in react.

Comment: Please show us your code to provide some insights/help on the basis of it.

Comment: @Alita S please provide code so that we could help you

Comment: i have added the code above. can u check the need full and ask me

Comment: @AlitaS can you give us some sample data, before it is sorted and after?

Comment: u mean after i created function to sort it @kobe

Comment: @AlitaS Yes, give us a sample of your data, then what you expect it to be after it has been sorted

Comment: (https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#variations-sortable) i want to be done like how its done in this website @kobe

Comment: anything on this solution  @kobe

Comment: @AlitaS I don't understand your question enough to the point where I can't understand what you want.

Comment: @AlitaS You don't want to sort the physical structure, but rather the datasource. That's why I asked for your datasource, before and after. Then, you can apply the sort with a function.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using data table it comes with sort functionality or you can make use of sortBy function from lodash library.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following code for sorting in ascending for

```
const sortedData = Object.assign([], someData).sort((a, b) => {
                                    if (a.sortByField > b.sortByField) return 1;
                                    if (a.sortByField < b.sortByField) return -1;

                                    return 0;
                                });
```

For descending order, the just change the conditional operators signs, making it

```
const sortedData = Object.assign([], someData).sort((a, b) => {
                                    if (a.sortByField< b.sortByField) return 1;
                                    if (a.sortByField > b.sortByField) return -1;

                                    return 0;
                                });
```

Comment: You mentioned clicking on a button. Create a button first, and an event to that button, and on that event you need to sort the data like I mentioned above. Use the state to store updated data, and then in render display the value stored in state.

Comment: can i get more assistance

Comment: Sure, go ahead.